# Create executable jar with maven in eclipse - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, executable

Since now a week, I'm trying to create an executable jar with maven in eclipse but I'm facing troubles. Here is what I have and what I do :

The content of my pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>B4D</groupId>
  <artifactId>B4D</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>B4D</name>
  <description>Bot for Dofus</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>fr.B4D.gui.JFrame_B4D</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev493-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sqladmin</artifactId>
        <version>v1beta4-rev66-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev136-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kirviq</groupId>
        <artifactId>dumbster</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jpcap</groupId>
        <artifactId>capture</artifactId>
        <version>0.01.16</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/jpcap/net.sourceforge.jpcap-0.01.16.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

I build my project by doing :

> Project > Run As > Maven build > Goals : package > Run

And here is the console output :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for B4D:B4D:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for net.sourceforge.jpcap:capture:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/jpcap/net.sourceforge.jpcap-0.01.16.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 115, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building B4D 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ B4D ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 32 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ B4D ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 84 source files to D:\Lucas\Projets personnels\Eclipse Windows\B4D\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ B4D ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ B4D ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to D:\Lucas\Projets personnels\Eclipse Windows\B4D\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ B4D ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ B4D ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Lucas\Projets personnels\Eclipse Windows\B4D\target\B4D-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) @ B4D ---
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
................
[INFO] com/google/api/ already added, skipping
[INFO] com/google/api/services/ already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:01 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-14T16:54:57+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And when I try to run the jar file in a console :

```
$ java -jar B4D-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/jpcap                                                                                                                                  /capture/InvalidFilterException
        at fr.B4D.gui.JFrame_B4D.<init>(JFrame_B4D.java:64)
        at fr.B4D.gui.JFrame_B4D.main(JFrame_B4D.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jpcap.capture.Inval                                                                                                                                  idFilterException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Note that my project use a local jar file dependency : net.sourceforge.jpcap-0.01.16.jar. It looks like this dependency is wrongly include in the final jar file. Of course, I've found a lot of topics about how to create an executable jar file and how to include a .jar file. But none of them solved my problem. There should be something wrong in my pom.xml but what ?

Thanks a lot

MrDomoo

Comment: The jpcap dependency is marked as `<scope>system</scope>`. Why don't us use the one from the [Top-Q Public repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jpcap/net-sourcedorge-jpcap/0.01.16)? You just have to add it as additional repo to your pom.xml.

Comment: Don't use the `<scope>system</scope>` and `<systemPath>`, you declare those dependencies as *available on the system the jar is running on*. You need to install this jar in the local repository in maven. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project)...

Comment: Your src directory definition is strange.

Comment: Try adding maven dependency `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jpcap/net-sourcedorge-jpcap -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jpcap</groupId>
    <artifactId>net-sourcedorge-jpcap</artifactId>
    <version>0.01.16</version>
</dependency>
` and remove scope. It should then work.

Comment: Hi everybody ! First, thanks for your answers. @Rober : I'm not using the remote repo because it says **Missing artifact net.sourceforge.jpcap:net-sourcedorge-jpcap:jar:0.01.16**

Comment: You are using the dependency but have not added repo. The dependency does not contain the info in which repo it is located. Therefore you have to add the repo manually: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to use the [Top-Q Public repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jpcap/net-sourcedorge-jpcap/0.01.16) because the artifact is missing.
So I had to install the JAR into my local Maven repository :

> Run > Run Configurations > Maven Build (double click)

The goal is :

```
install:install-file -Dfile=${basedir}/src/main/resources/net.sourceforge.jpcap-0.01.16.jar -DgroupId=net.sourceforge.jpcap -DartifactId=local -Dversion=0.01.16 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I can now in the pom.xml, simply use :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jpcap</groupId>
    <artifactId>local</artifactId>
    <version>0.01.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to [deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712135/dehaar)